# Failed to generate SSH key

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I am trying to generate an SSH key for my GitHub account but it's not working.

I am running the following commands in my terminal and both fail:

1. ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "my email"
2. ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -C "my email"

The error I am getting is:
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Key enrollment failed: device not found.

I have homebrew installed and before the installation of homebrew I managed to generate an SSH key but then when I tried to add it to my Github account I had an error message in Github saying: "Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format" but my key was in public format ending with .pub
What am I supposed to do to generate the SSH key?

Answer (score 3):

The `-sk` key types explicitly call for the presence of a hardware security key, but it doesn't sounds like you have added one. Either add a FIDO2-compliant hardware key, or change the type argument to either `ecdsa` or `ed25519` (without the `-sk`).